# Change button name on click and saving it

Tags: javascript, html

My button

```
<button id="status" onclick="myFunction()">Oczekująca</button>
```

And JS

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var btn = document.getElementById("status");
if (btn.innerHTML=="Oczekująca") btn.innerHTML = "Zakończona";
else btn.innerHTML = "Oczekująca";
}
</script>
```

Now it changes name on click but when i refresh the page the name is always "Oczekująca" is there a way the name will stay on "Zakończona" even after i refresh the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Window.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to save the button label (or any other information) between page loads:

```html
<button id="status" onclick="myFunction()">Oczekująca</button>

<script>
var btn = document.getElementById("status");

function myFunction() {
  if (btn.innerHTML=="Oczekująca") btn.innerHTML = "Zakończona";
  else btn.innerHTML = "Oczekująca";

  // save the current label to localStorage via setItem()
  window.localStorage.setItem('btnLabel', btn.innerHTML);
}

// on page load, get the saved label from localStorage via getItem()
var btnLabel = window.localStorage.getItem('btnLabel');
if (btnLabel) {
  btn.innerHTML = btnLabel;
}
</script>
```

See a working example here, as `localStorage` does not work in Stack Snippets for security reasons: https://jsfiddle.net/2wm6cgkn/

Answer (score 1):

You can play with the storage
Storage.setItem() and Storage.getItem()
To set the text